# Is there any other way to make pascal triangle?

Tags: c++, recursion, parameters, cout, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to print out the pascal triangle.

and this is a normal one

```
int pascal(int l, int n) {


    if (l == n || n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return pascal(l - 1, n) + pascal(l - 1, n - 1);

}
```

but I want to use only one pascal function for recursion like

```
int pascal(int l, int n) {


    return pascal();

}
```

Is there any solution for given condition?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do by memoization because there is an overlapping subproblem.

```
int pascalTriangle(int row, int col) {
    if (col == 0)
        return 1;
    if (row == 0)
        return col;
    return row * pascalTriangle(row - 1, col - 1) / col;
}
```

Comment: that's cool! I finally solved my problem with this!

Comment: That's a good answer but I can't see how it's memoisation when nothing is actually being memoised :-) This is just a standard recursive solution. Memoisation would be, for example, storing some already-calculated results in a container for returning later without recalculating.

Comment: Additionally, it makes more sense to use `row` and `col` variables rather than stating `l` is  the row and `n` is the column, ***especially*** since it's sometimes hard to tell the difference between `l` and `1`.

Comment: Additionallyally, the `if condition return else something` construct is one of those things that you should be avoiding - the `else` is totally unnecessary in cases like that, rendered useless by the `return`.

Comment: Having said all that, it's still a very good answer. Offering advice rather than criticism so upvoting. But I still think you should get rid of the memoisation claim :-)